# Is it possible to modify a schema using the rest API in Apache Solr?

Tags: solr, solr4

I think the title is self-explanatory.

I don't see anything on the Apache Solr wiki that suggests you can maintain the schema of an Apache Solr instance using the ReST API, but maybe (hopefully) you know something I don't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found a section on the [Solr wiki](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/FrontPage) where they describe this exact feature for release 4.4 (which is not released yet).

It does have some prerequisite configuration on the Solr instance, but it does allow you to add fields to the schema. Based on that information, I can't see why they won't eventually extend the functionality to allow you to delete as well. I guess we will have to wait and see.

Here is the link to that section: http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SchemaRESTAPI#Adding_fields_to_a_schema. It also references this JIRA issue: "[In preparation for dynamic schema modification via REST API, add a "managed" schema facility](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-4658)".

Comment: @mydoghasworms Don't you know whether it is possible to create a core with managed-schema through REST API? Otherwise, I find it contradictory, that there is a way to create "simple" schema through REST API wich however can not be modified through REST API, and there is no way to create managed-schema through REST API, but it can be easily modified with REST API.